# Browser version of Excel bypassing slicer protection

Tags: excel

In an Excel file I maintain we have slicers connected to a pivot table which then flows data through a report based on the slicer's selection.

We distribute this file to about 400 people by running a macro which selects one of the slicer options, then protects each sheet along with locking the slicer.

When opening the distributed file in the Excel application, it works as intended, not allowing users to make any other selections on the slicers.

When opening the same file in the browser version of Excel, the locking of slicers is bypassed and users are able to make selections within the slicers when they should not be able to. Interesting as the sheet remains protected, just slicers are unlocked.

I am unable to find a solution for keeping the slicers locked in the browser version of Excel. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements and funcitonality in Excel for Desktop work in Excel online. The Excel team is constantly adding new features to the online version, but full feature parity might still take a long time to arrive.

Not a solution to your issue, but there's nothing you or anyone can do about it.